# Close other div and keep selected one open on dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to hide all the siblings

I have a layout like this

```
                <label class=""><b>Design Level</b>
                    <select class="static-website">
                            <option>--------Select--------</option>
                            <option value="basic-design">Basic Design</option>
                            <option value="business-design">Business Design</option>
                            <option value="creative-design">Creative Design</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                 <br/>

            <div class="static-basic-design">

                <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
                    <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="5" />
                </label>

             </div><!-- End of Basic Static Box -->

             <div class="static-business-design">

                <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
                    <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="10" />
                </label>

             </div><!-- End of BUSINESS Static Box -->

             <div class="static-creative-design">

                <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
                    <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="5" />
                </label>

             </div><!-- End of Creative Static Box -->
```

We have our jquery written like this:

=

```
$(".static-website select").on('change',function(e){
    var selectedopt=$(this).val();
    $('.static-'+selectedopt).siblings().hide(); (this is not working)
    $('.static-'+selectedopt).show();

});
```

But it seems like $('.static-'+selectedopt).siblings().hide(); this is not working.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the rest of your HTML?

Comment: should be `siblings()` instead of `siblinks`

Comment: See jQeury siblinks documentation http://api.jquery.com/siblinks/

Comment: Ok i added some elements for you...I will be waiting for your response. dave

Comment: Dude, @SamBattat, WTH. And why did people +1 you? Your link went to a 404!

Comment: @user3201500, I always appreciate a live version to look at rather than digging through your code... post a jsFiddle, please!

Comment: 404? EXACTLY MY POINT

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a6kne66b/3/ live version of what i am trying to create

Comment: @philtune here is for you. http://jsfiddle.net/a6kne66b/3/

Comment: @SamBattat hahah, gottcha! I've read so much terrible spelling today.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was your on change selector `$(".static-website select")` gets you all `select` tags under `.static-website`, but what you wanted was `.static-website` itself. Also, you'll probably want to filter the siblings for just the divs.

```js
$(".static-website").on('change', function(e) {
  var selectedopt = $(this).val();
  $('.static-' + selectedopt).siblings("div").hide();
  $('.static-' + selectedopt).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class=""><b>Design Level</b>
  <select class="static-website">
    <option>--------Select--------</option>
    <option value="basic-design">Basic Design</option>
    <option value="business-design">Business Design</option>
    <option value="creative-design">Creative Design</option>
  </select>
</label>
<br/>

<div class="static-basic-design">

  <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
    <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="5" />
  </label>

</div>
<!-- End of Basic Static Box -->

<div class="static-business-design">

  <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
    <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="10" />
  </label>

</div>
<!-- End of BUSINESS Static Box -->

<div class="static-creative-design">

  <label class="no-pages-static"><b>Number Of Pages</b>
    <input type="text" name="no-pages-static" value="5" />
  </label>

</div>
<!-- End of Creative Static Box -->
```

Comment: Hello, Here is how it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/a6kne66b/3/ please now you will get an idea